# Spring security : OAuth related classes -AuthorizationServerTokenServices , Oauth2AccessToken not available

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Are below classes removed in spring security by spring boot 2.4.1

import org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Authentication
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.OAuth2Request
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.AuthorizationServerTokenServices
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.TokenStore

they can neither be found in

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

nor  in

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Where can we find these if using spring boot 2.4.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

those classes are not and have never been part of `spring boot`.

They are part of [`spring-security-oauth`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth) which was deprecated when spring security 5 was released.

Each of the deprecation notices links the the [`oauth 2.0 migration guide`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide)